# Open CV crashes under WIN7 when opening NamedWindow

Tags: opencv, mingw

I am having trouble with OpenCV2.0 on Win7 32bit, I have recompiled it using MinGW 4.5.0 and everything went OK until I tried to run examples.  Anytime it opens NamedWindow it crashs down. On the other side on on different machine Win7 64 bit everything runs without problem. Any idea?

Thx, Jan

Comment: Did you compile opencv on both 32bit and 64bit? Maybe you have 64bit DLL files on the 32bit system?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known problem due to some sort of "stack misalignment" with SSE under certain circumstances.

It has been posted before [namedWindow() causes crash in opencv 2.3.1? (Eclipse+MinGW on XP, C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996032/namedwindow-causes-crash-in-opencv-2-3-1-eclipsemingw-on-xp-c)

/Lars

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are picking up the correct DLLs, and if you built with Qt, that you are getting the correct Qt DLLs.

Did you just install somethign that also uses Qt - but a different version (like AMDs codeprofiler)